# Correct way to express the cardinality of a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$. 
We know that $A$ is finite, as $p$ is finite, and that the cardinality of $A$ is $p$, as the $k$ values are unique values.
If I want to put this statement in a mathematical way, how should I do it correctly?
Can I just say $|A| = p$, because $1≤k≤p$, or what is the correct way?

Comment: $|A|=p$ is correct.

Comment: That depends on how rigorous you want to be... I would argue that the statement that $|A|=p$ is obvious and needs no justification (*since the very definition of a set having cardinality $p$ with $p$ finite is that there is some bijection from that set to the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,p\}$... the bijection for your case being obvious as it is merely the identity map*)

Comment: I need to be as rigorous as possible. I also feel that this needs justification and I need some idea.

Comment: Note that while people do use the notation $|A|$ for the cardinality of a set, $\#A$ is a better notation, as $|\cdot|$ is far overused in mathematics.

Comment: Can we say that A is finite, as p is finite. Elements of A are distinct. A contains every positive integer up to p. Therefore the cardinality of A is the highest number in A, that is p.